# Text View not getting updated. Seems fine while debugging

Tags: android, textview, runnable

I have 2 virtually identical textviews in a layout that are updated by 2 similar bits of code. When the app runs (whether emulator or phone) one is updated but the other is not - but when run the same way in debug mode they are both updated. I've done lots of searching online, read lots of questions and answers and have tried various ways to update the `textview`, but the weird thing is this combination: it works in debug but not live, but another `texview` and a canvas are updated ok. Even a log message (placed in the same if clause as this `textview` update) works in debug but not when run on emulator (other log messages are being 
displayed ok).

The layout also has a canvas used for a simple game and the relevant code is within the running of that game. The canvas is updated by a repeating runnable. I wanted to add a time limit to the game so thought I'd simply mark the start time and then check in the runnable the time since the start. The textview is intended to show the seconds passing - and it works in debug! Abbreviated version of code below.

Maybe it's something about timing, something not having time to run properly? It doesn't need another runnable, does it, seeing as it's managing to update the other textview ok? Should you do runnables within runnables?
Any help or guidance appreciated.

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/trees2"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".GameActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/the_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="" />
<couk.jit.drawing.GameBoard
    android:id="@+id/the_canvas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

GameBoard.java

```
public class GameBoard extends View {
public GameBoard(Context context, AttributeSet aSet) {
    super(context, aSet);
    p = new Paint();
    sprite1 = new Point(-1,-1);
    m = new Matrix();
    bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b1);
    sprite1Bounds = new Rect(0,0, bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight());
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.go_sign);
}
synchronized public boolean didItHitTarget() {
if .... return true;
else ... return false;
}
@Override
synchronized public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), p);
      canvas.drawBitmap(bm3, sprite3.x, sprite3.y, null);
}
}
```

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final int FRAME_RATE = 20;
long startTime;
int timerCount = 0;
int score = 0;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            initGfx();
                    }
     }, 1000);
}
synchronized public void initGfx() {
    Point p1, p2;
    p1 = getStartPoint();
    ((GameBoard)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).setSprite1(p1.x, p1.y);
    ((View)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).setOnTouchListener(this);
  frame.removeCallbacks(frameUpdate);
  frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
}
private Runnable frameUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    synchronized public void run() {
        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            updateReady();
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            updateRunning();
    }
    synchronized public void updateReady() {
        frame.removeCallbacks(frameUpdate);
        ((GameBoard)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).invalidate();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();  //set game start time
        frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
    }
    synchronized public void updateRunning() {
        frame.removeCallbacks(frameUpdate);
        if (((GameBoard)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).didItHitTarget()) {
            score = score + 1;
//This works fine
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score)).setText(Integer.toString(score));
            Point p1;
            p1 = getStartPoint();
            ((GameBoard)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).setSprite1(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
        float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 100000000000.0f;
        int j = (int) deltaTime;
        if ((int)deltaTime > timerCount) {
            timerCount = timerCount + 1;
//This works in debug but does not update live
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdown)).setText(Integer.toString(timerCount));
            Log.i(TAG, "Updating countdown");
        }
        ((GameBoard)findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).invalidate();
        frame.postDelayed(frameUpdate, FRAME_RATE);
    }
};
```

Comment: can your read  Log.i(TAG, "Updating countdown"); on your console?

Comment: Yes, I can read Log.i(TAG, "Updating countdown") when in debug but not when run normally.

Comment: that means that the if condition is never true

Comment: I can't argue with your logic, blackbelt, but I'm at a loss to understand how. I believe I'm doing the same thing (debug/live); in debug I see it enter that clause at right time; previous if clause works as expected.

Comment: you are relyin on time at nano granularity. From debug/release that's a thing that matters

Comment: Sorry blackbelt, what do you mean by 'from debug/release'? And is eg getTimeInMillis better?

Comment: It is your application. You have to kwnow when that condition should be true. For debug/release I mean debug/live

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution in case anyone interested (or can still suggest better way!).
Going from blackbelt's point that certain parts of the code are simply not being entered, I thought that, although I couldn't find the reason, it must be something to do with the complexity of the timer clock combined with android's thread handling. So I created the timer using a separate thread, as in code here:
[Android update TextView in Thread and Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716850/android-update-textview-in-thread-and-runnable)