# Thumbnail of website by the url - ANDROID

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I am in the middle of creating an app, in that if user put a **website url**
it will automatically convert to the **website thumbnail**. I made a http connection and got the **html page as response**. In that there is a meta tag that have the image/thumbnail.

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
```

So **my question is how to extract** that  image.

I tried **Jsoup** , I cant extract the image from that.

Geeks please help me

Answer (score 6):

Use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for extracting `website thumbnail` from HTML `meta` tag

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(WEBSITE_URL).get();
Elements elements=doc.select("meta");

for(Element e: elements){
  //fetch image url from content attribute of meta tag. 
  imageUrl = e.attr("content");

  //OR more specifically you can check meta property.
  if(e.attr("property").equalsIgnoreCase("og:image")){
     imageUrl = e.attr("content");
     break;
  } 
}
```

Now use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) An image loading and caching library for Android.

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: +1 for answer...but this solution will  cause issue on main thread ..so use  Handler, to post to the UI Thread: link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716850/android-update-textview-in-thread-and-runnable