# programmatically set the selected property of a list item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my app I have two items in the Navigation Drawer which represent two modes:

**1) All Countries Quiz

2) Favorite Quiz**

When the user selects `Favorite Quiz` mode the application will check a particular condition. What I want is if the condition fails then I want to programatically set the selected property of the `All Countries Quiz` list item to checked. Basically it should revert to first mode if the condition of second mode fails.

**Something like this:**

1) User is currently on - All Countries Quiz Mode

[image]

2) Now user clicks on - Favorite Quiz Mode. If the condition is true then the everything goes normal and selector shift to second mode:

[image]

3) But if the condition fails, then the selection should not move to 2nd mode and should remain on 1st mode:

[image]

**Here's the menu list code for the items on Navigation Drawer:**

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_quiz_all"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_black_24dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:title="All Countries Quiz"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_quiz_bookmarked"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="Favorite Quiz"/>
</group>


<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            android:title="Rate this app"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:title="Share"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback_black_24dp"
            android:title="Feedback"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:title="About"/>
    </menu>
</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:title="Settings"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use: `setCheckedItem()` method of `NavigationView`

snippet of code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if(condition){
      mNavigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_item);  //yOur Item
    }
    mNavigationView.setCheckedItem(item.getItemId());

}
```

**EDIT**

you can use the following code snippet: call it in your activity when the condition applies..

```
mNavigationView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_item);
    }
});
```

Comment: `mNavView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_quiz_all);` not working. Any alternatives ?

Comment: it helps to refresh the UI elements properly...pls see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716850/android-update-textview-in-thread-and-runnable